# Looking for a word that means "overly conciliatory"

Tags: single-word-requests

Taking an Ethics class, and in a unit of Aristotelean Virtue ethics, we are covering "The Mean."

Is there a word that means roughly, "seeking middle ground for middle ground's sake; compromising to a fault?" Seeking a middle ground or happy medium not because it is optimal or virtuous to do so, but just because it is the midpoint between two extremes of a certain behavior?

Thank you!

Comment: Does the word *appeasing* (or *appeasement*) fit your use case?

Comment: I think it could. Thank you!

Comment: To be clear 'appeasing' means 'overly conciliatory' and 'compromising to a fault' but does not mean 'seeking a middle ground' -or-being non-extreme -or-  doing something out of esthetic balance (that's all I can figure out of your words) instead of optimality or virtue. So can you clarify which of these you are really seeking?

Comment: *Grovel* is the word a critic might use.

Comment: The answer will require more context. There are different ways people may seek middle ground. Politics is a salient one. In that case, the term **centrist** seems most fitting. **Temperance** is a term usually applied to the *appetites*, in which case it is bound to be understood normatively and hence as a virtue. Still, there are others. Some people are **mediocrists** by choice, and this refers to their *abilities* or *qualities.*

Comment: The first sentence of the question is more confusing than helpful. In the context of Aristotle's ethics, *mean* is a well-established term, and it would be misguided to try to replace it with something else. If the second paragraph is meant to be the operative part of the question, then it is not clear how the preceding sentence is supposed to illuminate it, as Aristotle certainly did not think of what he was doing in the way suggested in the second paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an exact match, but an ***accommodationist*** is pretty close:

> A person who seeks compromise with an opposing point of view, typically a political one.
> <sub>[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/accommodationist)</sub>

As noted, the word has a political connotation, and is also a term used to describe a judicial interpretation of how government should interact with religion.

> ... ***Accommodationists*** espouse the view that "religious individuals, and/or religious entities may be accommodated by government in regard to such things as free exercise rights, access to government programs and facilities, and religious expression."
> <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accommodationism)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

***Appeasing***, while nominally neutral, can carry the connotation you mention, that of conciliation just for the sake of ending discussion.

***[M/W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appease)*** has:

> (1) pacify, conciliate, especially : to make concessions to (someone,
> such as an aggressor or a critic) often at the sacrifice of principles

Comment: This is emphasizing making concessions to make another person happy. The question is about the middle ground for the middle ground's sake.

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me of the Confucius approach to the world called the Doctrine of the (Golden) Mean (Zhong Yong). So you could say that someone is a subscriber of the Golden Mean. You could read more about it here: [The Golden Mean](https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Golden_mean_(philosophy))

Comment: They couldn't subscribe to that idea if they haven't heard of it and all that it entails.

Answer (score 0):

I like temperate as well, but will add [centrist](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/centrist) to the list.  Temperate, to me, implies a character trait, while centrist seems more focused on the center in an active or political sense.

Answer (score 0):

“mewling” is a good word to capture the weak-willed connotation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).